# How to remove or change Magento copyright section from admin login

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, copyright

I am trying to remove a Magento `copyright` text from `admin login` area, but I am not sure How I can do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove it:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```